# NSTask Until Interrupted Command in Cocoa / Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, cocoa, nstask

I am trying to use NSTask on to run an ASR Multicast Stream, a Ruby Server Script, etc. Basically, I'm trying to run tasks with NSTask that do not finish running until interrupted, but the problem is that I can't get the NSTask to run in the background. So it ends up just running and holding up the rest of my program. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTask` shouldn't block your program unless you call the `waitUntilExit` method.  If you have to do that, you could make a new thread and start/wait for your `NSTask` from inside it.  As an alternative to blocking, you could look into `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification`.  The [`NSTask` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) covers all of these options.

Comment: Well, I do all of the set up for the NSTask. I put a NSLog(@"BEFORE");, then I call [task launch];. Following that line, I put a simple NSLog(@"AFTER");. The BEFORE gets printed but not the AFTER.